# Make Google Talk open links in Chrome

Tags: file-association, google-talk

I use Google Talk to check my gmail.

For reasons unknown to me Google Talk insists on opening Firefox when I receive an email and click on the popup. Is there a way to make it open links in Chrome instead?

Comment: Which Operating System?

Comment: Is chrome your default browser? Most likely your system is just opening the links with the application you have specified as your default browser.

Comment: Windows, and Chrome's the default browser, not Firefox. In fact when I click on the new email popup firefox even asks if I want to make it my default browser. I tried restarting and it is still using Firefox to open links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out.

Needed to change Windows' file association for http:// - it's very strange that although Chrome had been set as the default browser the file association was still pointing to Firefox.

Comment: This is a Windows issue. It is Windows, through you,  that sets file associations and neither Firefox nor Chrome can do anything about that on their own.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Internet Properties -> Programs -> Set Programs -> Set program access and computer defaults. Expand "Custom" and choose "Google Chrome". Select "Enable access to this program".

Now launch mail from gtalk :)